# Django file uploading function can run in localhost but can't run in EC2 instance of AWS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

So I'm trying to create a chatbot webapp that can do data analysis from an excel, csv, google spreadsheet, and all sorts. It's good when I ran it in the local anaconda environment, and now I want to set it up in the AWS EC2. But then things happen, you see when I get it run in the locals it doesn't give error on the inspect and then comes this new 2 error:

> - POST https:/demo.myapp.company/upload/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
> - Error uploading file: Error: Network response was not ok Internal Server Error
>   at (index):646:16

But in my local anaconda environment it doesn't yield that, as a matter fact it always successfully uploaded files with no fail (around 50 times as per now without any error). I asked openai's chatgpt and says this error falls on the server side and has nothing to do with the code so then I tried using all 12 suggestions and nothing worked, anyone familiar with this kind of error?

The app pipeline will look like this:

1. User clicked the upload button and select the excel file, here's how the file is handled in django:
   On the `views.py`:

```py
import requests, boto3, pandas, etc.
def file_upload(request):
    act = tbl_Generate_Session.objects.filter(user = request.user).filter(status = 1).last()
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'file' in request.FILES:
        file = request.FILES['file']
        bucket_name = 'mybucket'
        folder_name = 'worksheets/'
        file_extension = file.name.split('.')[-1].lower()
        last_worksheet = #last worksheet on the models table
        numb = #unique id
        if file_extension in ['xls', 'xlsx']:
            wsname = f"{act.sessionid}-{numb}.xlsx"
        elif file_extension == 'csv':
            wsname = f"{act.sessionid}-{numb}.csv"
        else:
            pass
        storage = S3Boto3Storage()
        file_path = folder_name + wsname
        file_name = storage.save(file_path, file)
        aws_url = f"https://{bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com/{file_path}"
        df = #retrieve the sheet from s3 and make it as a dataframe
        if file_extension in ['xls', 'xlsx']:
            countsheet = #count the sheet
            if countsheet>1:
                #handle multisheet excel file
            elif countsheet==1:
                #handle excel single sheet file
            else:
                result = None
        elif file_extension == 'csv':
            #handle csv
        else:
            pass
        #then save the schema and save the link to s3 in the models.py table
        return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'filename': file_name, "res": "Successfuly import excel file into dataframe", "savethis": savethis})
    return JsonResponse({'success': False})
```

On the `settings.py` I made it like this

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages',
    'myapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = AWS_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = SECRET_KEY
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATIC_URL = '/static/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/vol/web/static'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/vol/web/media'
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'https://www.myapp.digital'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://www.myapp.digital","http://www.myapp.digital"]
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

2. The file is then auto-uploaded to s3 after opened (using javascript, I made it so that after user click open on the file it gets automatically uploaded). Idk if there's something wrong with this but I sincerely hope not:

```js
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                var fileInput = document.getElementById('file-upload');
                if (fileInput) {
                    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
                        if (this.files && this.files.length > 0) {
                            var formData = new FormData();
                            formData.append('file', this.files[0]);
                            formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', getCookie('csrftoken'));                         
                            fetch("/upload/", {
                                method: 'POST',
                                body: formData,
                            })
                            .then(response => {
                                if (!response.ok) {
                                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok ' + response.statusText);
                                }
                                return response.json();
                            })
                            .then(data => {
                                console.log(data);
                                alert('File uploaded successfully!');
                                var chatHistory = document.getElementById('bot-chat-container');
                                var messageTemplate = document.getElementById('message-template');
                                var messageClone = messageTemplate.cloneNode(true);
                                messageClone.style.display = 'block';
                                messageClone.querySelector('.message-content').textContent = data.savethis;
                                chatHistory.appendChild(messageClone);
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
</script>
```

And for your record, this script uses csrf token in it's usage so it doesn't get a permission error or something from the browser
3. File is then saved to s3 and then we access it using IAM (WHICH IN THIS PIPELINE OF A PROCESS, THE ERROR HAPPENS BEFORE THIS STAGE BECAUSE THE ONES FROME EC2 SOMEHOW NEVER GOES TO S3 BUT THE LOCAL PASSED THIS THING). Now here's what I have tried in my AWS:

1. Setting my s3 bucket policy to:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Setting my ec2 instance IAM role with policy below :

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and assign `S3FullAccess` to that role too
3. Configured the EC2 instance normally